# Using ObjectId parameters in Pentaho reporting against MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reporting, pentaho

I'm using Pentaho to report against MongoDB. In the transformation my query is an aggregation pipeline and is as follows:

```
[   
{$match: {billing_cycle_id: "${billing_cycle}"} },
{
    $project : {
        account_id : 1,
        age_120.cents : 1,
        age_60.cents : 1,
        age_30.cents: 1,
        balance.cents: 1,
        billing_cycle_id : 1,
        transaction_line_items : 1
    }
},
{$unwind : "$transaction_line_items"}
]
```

The default value of ${billing_cycle} is 5162f1c0b7228a2793000011

So here is the query from the Pentaho logs:

```
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 - Query pulled data from: [   
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -     {$match: {billing_cycle_id: "5162f1c0b7228a2793000011"} },
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -     {
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -         $project : {
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -             account_id : 1,
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -             age_120.cents : 1,
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -             age_60.cents : 1,
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -             age_30.cents: 1,
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -             balance.cents: 1,
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -             billing_cycle_id : 1,
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -             transaction_line_items : 1
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -         }
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -     },
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 -     {$unwind : "$transaction_line_items"}
2013/12/12 09:57:12 - MongoDB Input.0 - ]
```

I'm guessing the problem is that this doesn't return any data because billing_cycle_id is an ObjectId but when I change the query to

```
[   
{$match: {billing_cycle_id: ObjectId("${billing_cycle}")} },
{
    $project : {
        account_id : 1,
        age_120.cents : 1,
        age_60.cents : 1,
        age_30.cents: 1,
        balance.cents: 1,
        billing_cycle_id : 1,
        transaction_line_items : 1
    }
},
{$unwind : "$transaction_line_items"}
]
```

Pentaho errors out on the query. How can I successfully use ObjectId in parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I had Same issues when I want to pass id comparison in mongodb input query steps. After that I  found solution I compare mongoid in pentaho query as below

```
{ "_id" :{'$oid':"52a5f2aee4b08d0d5ca1f3f5"}}
```

I think in your case you should go following way

```
[   
     {$match: {billing_cycle_id: {'$oid':"${billing_cycle}"}}},
       {
        $project : {
        account_id : 1,
        age_120.cents : 1,
        age_60.cents : 1,
        age_30.cents: 1,
        balance.cents: 1,
        billing_cycle_id : 1,
        transaction_line_items : 1
       }
    },
     {$unwind : "$transaction_line_items"}
]
```